# Save and Get all cookies in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to save the current location of the user when click in the button save, i am using the plugin "jquery.cookie.js"

HTML

```
<div id="popup-saveSearch">

    <!-- Save Cookie -->
    <input type="text" id="locationName">
    <button>Save</button>

    <!-- Show all Cookies Saved -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="location"><a href="#location1">cookie saved 1</a></td>
            <td class="location"><a href="#location2">cookie saved 2</a></td>
            <td class="location"><a href="#location3">cookie saved 3</a></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
// Save cookie
$("#popup-saveSearch  button").on('click',function(){
   var location = $("#locationName").val();
   var pathUrl = window.location.href;

   $.cookie('name',location);
   $.cookie("currentPath", pathUrl);
});
```

Now need to know how to make a each, with the saved cookie and show the table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with that idea, may be you can try like this

```
<table id="test-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="location"><a href="#location1">cookie saved 1</a> 
        </td>
        <td class="location"><a href="#location2">cookie saved 2</a>
        </td>
        <td class="location"><a href="#location3">cookie saved 3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$("table#test-table").find('tr').each(function() { });
```